# Vs code could not fint models values in django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

My models.py:

```py
class Service(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

And my views.py:

```
service = Service.objects.get(id=pk)
```

When I want to show which values have in Service object, Vs code doesnt prompt list of values. For instance, When I tpye `id=pk, na`, it must prompt value `name` of models

Which extension Have to I install?

Comment: The method catches arguments by `**kwargs` to map them to the model fields later. An IDE can not do this kind of logic for auto-completion, or at least it would have to be programmed into the extension for every framework separately.

Comment: It had runned before. Havent runned for 6 months